# display data on another form after selecting the option

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4, php-7

how, after I choose the option and then it will appear #formid where the form is filled in by the $stock as selected in the option section

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nama Item</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="itemId">
      <option selected>Choose</option>

      <?php $no=1; while($row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
        $stock  = $row->stock;
        $i_name = $row->i_name;
        $id     = $row->id;
        ?>

      <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $i_name; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>

    </select>
</div>
```

the form that will appear after selecting the option

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Stock</label>
    <input class="" type="number" name="" value="<?php echo $stock;?>">
</div>
```

I am new in php and javascript, can you write with a neat code & easy to understand, thank you :)

Comment: Ideally, you would use Javascript to solve this problem. Could you show us any Javascript code that you have tried already?

Comment: sorry, the purpose of this question is on the macrame answer, can you help me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the second div onSelect of the first one.

Because of the fact, that you use bootstrap I assume
that you have already included jQuery if not you have to do that for this example.

You have to add this JavaScript on your page.

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#exampleFormControlSelect1" ).change(function() {
    $("#secondDiv").show();
  });
 });

</script>
```

And you need an id on your div.

```
<div id="secondDiv" class="form-group">
    <label>Stock</label>
    <input class="" type="number" name="" value="<?php echo $stock;?>">
</div>
```

Comment: correct, I want to show the second div, but how to get a variable $stock according to the data selected on the option ?

Comment: For this you have to use ajax. Have a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript for this if you want the data to appear without the page reloading.
First we make Javascript Function that takes your option id and passes it to your input value.

```
funcction chooseOption(clicked.id){
document.getElementById('myInput').value = clicked_id;
}
```

HTML and PHP we need to add a different id for each option.  The best way it to pass the option name you want for each. We also added our onclick function to the options.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Nama Item</label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="itemId">
  <option selected>Choose</option>

  <?php $no=1; while($row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
    $stock  = $row->stock;
    $i_name = $row->i_name;
    $id     = $row->id;


 echo "<option onclick=\"chooseOption(this.id);\" id=\"".$stock."\" value=\"".$id."\">".$i_name."</option>";

  <?php } ?>

</select>
</div>
```

Added an id to your input so javascript can send the data to it.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Stock</label>
<input id="myInput" class="" type="number" name="" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, the purpose of this question is on the macrame answer, can you help me

Comment: I changes the var to stock that is being sent instead of $i_name.  Try this and let me know something

Comment: is the div with the input not visible and you want it to be?

Comment: Can you post your css?